# RavenDB - deleting previously-conflicted documents with "/conflicts" in URL

Tags: ravendb

I’m trying to programmatically delete once-conflicted documents that are no longer conflicted, but still showing as duplicates in Raven.

E.g. if I query an index on an entity’s property I know to be unique I get two documents back

1. Document A with URL entities/12345
2. Document B with URL entities/12345/conflicts/54321

My goal is to delete Document B.

Loading document A into a session does not throw a ConflictException, as it is not flagged as being conflicted any more. I can delete document B via the web UI, but can’t do it via code as yet, as I can only see it in transient context via a stream.

Here’s some sample code which explains what I am getting back from various client calls when trying to resolve this…

```
using (var enumerator = session.Advanced.Stream(query))
{
    while (enumerator.MoveNext()))
    {
        var entity = enumerator.Current.Document;

        // This attempt to get the id returns null
        var id = session.Advanced.GetDocumentId(entity);

        // Throws InvalidOperationException
        var url = session.Advanced.GetDocumentUrl(entity);

        // Returns null, so can’t use session to delete
        session.Load<TEntity>(entity);

        // Does nothing, with string ID of entity
        session.Advanced.Defer(new DeleteCommandData { Key = entity.Id.ToString() });

        // Does nothing
        session.Advanced.DocumentStore.DatabaseCommands.Delete(entity.Id.ToString(), null);
    }

    session.SaveChanges();
}
```

Any help would be gratefully received!

Answer (score 0):

I found that using `enumerator.Current.Key` in the example above gave me the key to the document I was after.